# How to call npm script with environment variable inside workflow step?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-actions

Given a .js file

```
const renderer = process.env.RENDERER;

if(!renderer) {
    console.log('missing');

    return;
}

console.log(renderer);
```

and a package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

I want to call the npm script inside my Github actions workflow but I want to pass the environment variable to it

```
name: Do

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      renderer:
        description: 'A,B,C,...'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  do:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 19.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Set environment variable for renderer
        run: export RENDERER=${{ inputs.renderer }}

      - name: Test output
        run: npm run dev
```

When running the workflow the script writes

> missing

to the console so it seems the npm script didn't run with the environment variable.

How can I prepend `RENDERER=${{ inputs.renderer }}` to `npm run dev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` character allows you to specify a multi-line command :

```yaml
- name: Test output
  run: |
    export RENDERER=${{ inputs.renderer }}
    npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `export`, there are two more alternatives:

By specifying `RENDERER` using the `env` context:

```
- name: Test output
  env:
    RENDERER: ${{ inputs.renderer }}
  run: npm run dev
```

and, by specifying `RENDERER=${{ inputs.renderer }}` before the command itself:

```
- name: Test output
  run: RENDERER=${{ inputs.renderer }} npm run dev
```